# SQL Count Innerjoin by Grouping

Tags: sql, count, group-by, inner-join

I have searched all the SQL questions and I have found every version of what I don't want - so I need to ask.  I am in a brain lock - knowing there is a count and sum and group and a join all thrown together.

**2 Tables**

1. CustomerTable - CustID, CustQuality (values are good customer, bad customer, new customer etc)
2. PurchaseTable (PurchID, PurchItem, PurchDate)

I am trying to count how many purchases by Good, Bad, New Customers in the last 30 days.

I have tried the join and group count etc and I keep getting:

- GoodCustomer - CustID2 - 1 purch
- GoodCustomer - CustID3 - 3 purch
- GoodCustomer - CustID4 - 2 purch
- BadCustomer - CustID7 - 2 purch
- BadCustomer - CustID1 - 4 purch
- NewCustomer - CustID9 - 1 purch
- NewCustomer - CustID4 - 4 purch etc etc.

**I just want the overall results**

- 3 Good Customers made 6 Purchases
- 2 Bad Customers made 6 Purchases
- 2 New Customers made 5 Purcahses

THEN FOR ADDITIONAL functioning...  I have a 3rd table that I need to join as well. CustomerLocation (CLID, CLLocation (values of North, South, East, West))

So if I wanted to know the following break down of the groups

- 3 Good Customers made 6 Purchases - 1 Customer was from the North, 2 Customers From South
- 2 Bad Customers made 6 Purchases - 5 Customer from East, 1 West
- 2 New Customers made 5 Purcahses - 2 Customer from South

And the last new query would be...
WHERE CLLocation = South

Or if I wanted to look up by region...

- 1 Good Customers made 3 Purchases
- 2 Bad Customers made 2 Purchases
- 0 New Customers made 0 Purcahses

**I KNOW I AM ASKING A LOT - BUT ANY AND ALL HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!**

Comment: could you specify the foreign key constraints of you tables?

Comment: CST.CustID - Primary for Customer, PCHT.PurchID - Primary for Purchase, PCHT.PurchCustID - foreign for Customer, LCT.LCTID - primary for Location, LCT.LCTCustID foreign for Customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT C.CustQuality, COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID) AS tot_Customer, COUNT(PurchID) AS tot_Purch
FROM CustomerTable C, PurchaseTable P
WHERE C.CustID = P.PurchCustID
GROUP BY C.CustQuality;

SELECT C.CustQuality, CL.CLocation,  COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID) AS tot_Customer, COUNT(PurchID) AS tot_Purch
FROM CustomerTable AS C, PurchaseTable AS P, CustomerLocation AS CL
WHERE C.CustID = P.PurchCustID AND CL.LCTCustID = C.CustID
GROUP BY C.CustQuality, CL.CLocation;

SELECT C.CustQuality, CL.CLocation,  COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID) AS tot_Customer, COUNT(PurchID) AS tot_Purch
FROM CustomerTable AS C, PurchaseTable AS P, CustomerLocation AS CL
WHERE C.CustID = P.PurchCustID AND CL.LCTCustID = C.CustID AND CL.CLocation='North'
GROUP BY C.CustQuality;
```

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID) keeps throwing me the error missing operator?

Comment: I just figured out why... I am writing the code via SQL but actually using access for the testing model.  Access does not "like" distinct.  Bummer!

Comment: if you can try to avoid ACCESS : D

Comment: agreed!  your code worked well as did Lukas - i just created (Select Distinct customerquality etc) in the from and it finally worked!  Thanks much to you both!

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your first question

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID), CustQuality, COUNT(PurchID) FROM CustomerTable c
INNER JOIN PurchaseTable p ON c.CustID = p.CustID
GROUP BY CustQuality
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I tried it but keep getting "missing operator" in COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID)

Comment: I saw that and fixed it in the original but I keep getting the same error COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustID) for some reason... driving me nuts!  Same as Rano's above.

Comment: I just figured out why... I am writing the code via SQL but actually using access for the testing model.  Access does not "like" distinct.  Bummer!